# How to set the transaction hash with useState in an Ethereum transaction

Tags: reactjs, transactions, react-hooks, ethereum

I would like to set a variable with React hooks.
Whenever I send an Ethereum transaction it is possible to get the hash of it through the method on('transactionHash', {...}) but if I try to call setTransactionHash nothing happens.
Here is the code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useCallback} from 'react';
import collegamentoConDb from '../api/collegamentocondb';
const Admin = ()=>{

    const [transactionHash, setTransactionHash] = useState("");
    ...
    try{
      window.ethereum.enable();
      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
      await contract.methods.notarizzazione(hashCampi).send({
        from:accounts[0]
      }).on('transactionHash', (hash)=>{
        setTransactionHash(hash)
      });
    
} catch(err){
  console.log(err);
}
//db call

   const fileTestoPdf = await collegamentoConDb.post('/creapdf', {id, transactionHash}); 
   ...
```

When I read the log file, transactionHash is not updated and I do not understand why. Can someone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Could you get hash in the console? if yes then try `const [transactionHash, setTransactionHash] = useState();`

Comment: No I can't. The console is blank. I am pretty sure the method I am using is correct because everything works without hooks.

Comment: Ok got it you can try 

`on('transactionHash', ((hash)=>{
        setTransactionHash(hash)
 });`

Comment: It does not work. If I console.log(transactionHash) after the transaction, it prints undefined.

Comment: can you please add code on codesandbox or StackBlitz so I can help more?

Comment: You can find part of my code here. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9khr3p